# Apply Manipulate on Image

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I tried to create a function to manipulate an image, where I can adjust some value color1, color2, val1, val2 and num and see the effect on image. Below is my code for processing an image with fixed values for color1, color2, val1, val2 and num.

How can I do it?

```
val1 = 0.4;
val2 = 0.4
num = 2000
color1 = Red
color2 = Black
imageno = 1;
img = images[[imageno]];
DeleteSmallComponents[
  MorphologicalComponents[
   RemoveBackground[img, {"Foreground", {color1, val1}}], num]];
im = RemoveBackground[img, {"Foreground", {color2, val2}}];
ima = EdgeDetect[im];

cen = ComponentMeasurements[
   ima, {"Centroid"}, #Holes == 1 && 
     10 < #Area && #AdjacentBorderCount == 0 &];

b = Flatten[cen /. Rule -> List, 2]; (* remove arrow*)

(*sort out even and odd element, even elements contain coordinate for \
hole*)
{x, y} = Partition[b, 2, 2, 1, {}]~Flatten~{2}; 
(*y : hole centroid location*)
dm = DelaunayMesh[y];

v = MeshPrimitives[dm, 0];
t = MeshPrimitives[dm, 2];

vedg = Length[Position[Level[t, {2}], #]] & /@ Level[v, {2}];
kN = Max[vedg];
mnloc = Flatten[Position[vedg, kN]];
mntri = Flatten[
   Position[ContainsAny[#, Level[v[[mnloc]], {2}]] & /@ Level[t, {2}],
     True]];

nc = t[[mntri]];
knpic = Graphics[{Red, {PointSize[0.01], Point[y]}, Green, 
    MeshPrimitives[dm, 1], {Opacity[0.5], FaceForm[Red], 
     EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], nc, FaceForm[Yellow]}}];
Show[img, knpic, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Comment: You  said yourself use manipulate.

Comment: but how can I do it, I tried to define a function for the code above and apply Manipluate to that function with changeable values for color1,color2 (Black,Blue,Green...etc), val1,val2(0.1-1,0.1) num(100-5000,100). But it didnt work

Comment: maybe you should try mathematica.stackexchange.com, but show the code you tried and say what it does wrong  ("didn't work" is useless)